# Python - Validation with multiple schemas using lxml

Tags: python, xsd, lxml

I'm working with a schema that was built by a third party and I'd like to validate it with lxml. The problem is that such a schema is split over different xsd files, which reference themselves.

For example, a file called "extension.xsd" (which builds upon the "master" schema) has a line like:

```
<redefine schemaLocation="master.xsd">
```

If I try to validate it with lxml (parsing, then using `XMLSchema` then validating another document which I know is valid already), I only get validation using "extension" and not "master": in  other words, the validation fails (because in the XML file there are elements only present in "master" and not in "extension").

How can I solve (or work around) this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If lxml doesn't support "redefine", the best option would be to fix it and submit a patch. :)

Failing that, the workaround would be to parse the master.xsd file yourself, and then apply the changes from extension.xsd, and output a single xsd file with the combined schema.